# How to convert Dataframe into key value pair list for every single raw?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

What is the best way to convert following pandas dataframe to a key value pair like below example:

```
dataframe:

   col1   col2  col3         col4
0    a    tom    90         Good
1    b    jay    75  Not so good
2    c  harsh    35          Bad
3    d    ras    50    impresive
```

it is possible to get lists like this
desired ouput:

```
[
 {
   'key':'col1',
   'value':'a'
 }
{
   'key':'col2',
   'value':'tom'
 }
{
   'key':'col3',
   'value':90,
 }
{
   'key':'col4',
   'value':'Good',
 }
]
[
 {
   'key':'col1',
   'value':'b'
 }
{
   'key':'col2',
   'value':'jay'
 }
{
   'key':'col3',
   'value':75,
 }
{
   'key':'col4',
   'value':'Not so good',
 }
]
```

...
for every raw

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more pythonic way:

```
>>> [[{'key': k, 'value': v} for v in l]
        for _, k, l in zip(*df.to_dict('split').values())]

[[{'key': 'col1', 'value': 'a'},
  {'key': 'col1', 'value': 'tom'},
  {'key': 'col1', 'value': 90},
  {'key': 'col1', 'value': 'Good'}],
 [{'key': 'col2', 'value': 'b'},
  {'key': 'col2', 'value': 'jay'},
  {'key': 'col2', 'value': 75},
  {'key': 'col2', 'value': 'Not so good'}],
 [{'key': 'col3', 'value': 'c'},
  {'key': 'col3', 'value': 'harsh'},
  {'key': 'col3', 'value': 35},
  {'key': 'col3', 'value': 'Bad'}],
 [{'key': 'col4', 'value': 'd'},
  {'key': 'col4', 'value': 'ras'},
  {'key': 'col4', 'value': 50},
  {'key': 'col4', 'value': 'impresive'}]]
```

---

**Old answer**
Use `melt` reshape your dataframe then group by index and finally export each group to a list of dict:

```
>>> [df.to_dict('records') for _, df in df.melt(var_name='key', value_name='value', ignore_index=False).groupby(level=0)]

[[{'key': 'col1', 'value': 'a'},
  {'key': 'col2', 'value': 'tom'},
  {'key': 'col3', 'value': 90},
  {'key': 'col4', 'value': 'Good'}],
 [{'key': 'col1', 'value': 'b'},
  {'key': 'col2', 'value': 'jay'},
  {'key': 'col3', 'value': 75},
  {'key': 'col4', 'value': 'Not so good'}],
 [{'key': 'col1', 'value': 'c'},
  {'key': 'col2', 'value': 'harsh'},
  {'key': 'col3', 'value': 35},
  {'key': 'col4', 'value': 'Bad'}],
 [{'key': 'col1', 'value': 'd'},
  {'key': 'col2', 'value': 'ras'},
  {'key': 'col3', 'value': 50},
  {'key': 'col4', 'value': 'impresive'}]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are a more elegant way to do this but here a quick solution:

```
diktionary_list = []
end_list = []
for nummer, col in enumerate(frame):
    for row in frame[col]:
        dickt = {}
        dickt["key"] =  col
        dickt["value"] = row
        diktionary_list.append(dickt)
        
    end_list.append(diktionary_list)
```